# How to fix: (node:12364) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated

Tags: node.js, angular

`ng serve -o` shows the following error message:

```
- Generating browser application bundles...(node:12364) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Then the terminal shows: `\ Generating browser application bundles (phase: emitting)...`

But the browser never opening, it seems VSC is in an endless loop.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 40):

Version compatibility could be the issue. Downgrading node js version from *16.8.0*  to *14.17.5*  resolved my issue.

Comment: Downgrading doesn't seems to be a definitely solution.

Comment: this could solve the problem. i suggest to use a node version manager (nvm for windows) if you want more then one node version installed at the same time

Comment: Used nvm to downgrade to v14 and it resolved my issue.

Comment: When you try to run an older Node.js application under a new version of Node.js you may get deprecation warnings. If you downgrade Node.js and keep the out of date component, you will introduce a dangerous security risk in your application.

To refresh the referenced Node.js libraries

In the command line execute

* npm install --force
* npm audit fix --force

Answer (score 8):

**I was working on a project, and suddenly i got to change to a different project. now node version supported by the new project is different from my local machine node version.**

So in this case i have used nvm to manage multiple node versions.
Here is how to install nvm. [Click](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/)

Go to cmd as administrator and now you need to install required node version like this.

1. Go to the project and type `ng v` to identify the required node version.
2. Go to your project and delele "package-lock.json" file and "node_modules" folder
3. Go to cmd as admin and type `nvm install [required node version]`
4. type `nvm use [required node version]`
5. Go to your project and hit `npm install --force`
6. And then `ng serve`

Now in this same way you can manage versions between multiple projects.

**Note : You should checkout your develop branch for git, This wouldn't be fix, if you checked out master branch, when you clone the project from repo, it will defaultly checked Master branch.**

Answer (score 5):

Downgrading is not the correct answer. It is likely that in your node server you are using  [SPDY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) in place of the newer http2 module. SPDY used the legacy parser deprecated in version 15 [Nodejs v 15.0.0 deprecations](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/deprecations.html#DEP0131)

See an example server here using ES6 and the http2 module: [node v 20 example server](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#server-side-example).

```
// const http2 = require('spdy');
const http2 = require('node:http2');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use nvm to switch between different node versions.
use this link to download nvm https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#readme

after that open a terminal and use commands

```
nvm list 
use 12.20.0(version that you need)
```

then you can use your angular, react, vuejs or nodejs commands as usual

Comment: https://catalins.tech/node-version-manager-macos/
Is a good resource for Mac people

Answer (score 3):

`set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && npm run start` , this works for me . type this code in terminal like in this image. [image]

Answer (score 2):

This issue is already due the incompatibility of the version of angular and node

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the actual error. I was facing the same issue and was stuck for a long time. Below this warning I had

```
'Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
   ...
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}'
```

this error. And it was solved when I updated the script in package.json

```
'"scripts": {
    "start": "**export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider &&** react-scripts start",
    "build": "**export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider &&** react-scripts build"
  }'
```

Also, I had to update my `webpack` version using the `npm i -D webpack@^4.0.0` command.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue when running Angular 9.1.13 then I solved it by the following.

```
yarn remove @prisma/cli
yarn add prisma --dev
yarn upgrade @prisma/client
```

> My environment:
>
> Angular CLI: 9.1.15, Node: 16.16.0, Angular: 9.1.13

Answer (score 0):

It is a node version compatibility issue. You need to downgrade your node to the required node version by the project or other dependencies. Go to your devDependencies in your package.json and see what stable node version worked fine last. Then download that node version, Using two different node versions is also possible using 'nvm'. The following [blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nvm-for-windows-how-to-download-and-install-node-version-manager-in-windows-10/#:%7E:text=To%20install%20a%20specific%20version,%2C%20nvm%20install%2014.20.0%20.) might help you in enabling the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `npm audit fix --force` command in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I used to resolve the warning:

1. [Install nvm](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/)
   (If you haven't installed it before, you need to restart your machine.)
2. Delete "package-lock.json" file and "node_modules" folder
3. In cmd (you may need to use it as admin), run `nvm install [required node version]`
4. Run `nvm use [required node version]`
5. In your project, run `npm install --force`
6. Finally try `ng serve -o` again.

I hope this helps.